# 4K - Windows 10 - JetBeans PhpStorm IDE - Scaling is making SVN checkout impossible

Tags: windows, phpstorm, resolution, scaling, screen-resolution

I have PhpStorm 10 on my new Windows 10 computer with a 4K display.  When I try to export my code from my subversion repository, the menu it gives is so small I cannot possibly type the repository web address into the box.

I have tried

1. Adding `-Dhidpi=true` to the bottom of the PhpStorm.exe.vmoptions (and PhpStorm64.exe.vmoptions) files and rebooting.
2. Rescaling my entire Windows resolution to 1080.
3. Setting a custom scaling level (of 100%, 250% and 400%) in `Control Panel -> All Control Panel Items -> Display`

Here is the problem I'm seeing, first in the 4K view, then again on a 1080 resolution:

4K: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NoQsg.jpg

1080: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42NQo.png

What do I need to change to fix this?

Comment: Please try 2016.3.2 (latest stable version) or 2017.1 EAP build -- they had quite few changes in HiDPI screens support since your version (which is over 1 year old now).

Comment: Doesn't that require a subscription license?  That's my only hang-up: I bought a perpetual license for 10 already.

Comment: Well -- each 2017.1 EAP build (until 2017.1 final will be released) comes with own 30-day license -- anyone can use it. At very least you can confirm if it's fixed there or not.